# Receiving data from Arduino to Android. Data gets mixed when button clicked

Tags: java, android, multithreading, bluetooth, arduino

When calling the `getTemp()` method with a button press, data is received correctly if I pressed that button more than once. But if I press the second button`getWeight()` after the first `getTemp()` data gets mixed and I receive random data in random order. I try to stop earlier stats thread in each function. But I get a null point exception. How to fix this?

```
public void getTemp() {
  //stopThread = true;
  sendData("t");
  final Handler handler = new Handler();
  stopThread = false;
  buffer = new byte[1024];
  thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
      while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() && !stopThread) {
        try {
          int byteCount = inputStream.available(); // -1
          if (byteCount > 0) {
            byte[] rawBytes = new byte[byteCount];
            inputStream.read(rawBytes);
            final String string = new String(rawBytes, "UTF-8");
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
              public void run() {
                textTemp.append(string);
              }
            }
            );
          }
        } 
        catch (IOException ex) {
          stopThread = true;
        }
      }
    }
  });
  thread.start();
}

public void getWeight() {
  sendData("w");
  final Handler handler = new Handler();
  stopThread = false;
  buffer = new byte[1024];
  thread1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
      while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() && !stopThread) {
        try {
          int byteCount = inputStream.available(); // -1
          if (byteCount > 0) {
            byte[] rawBytes = new byte[byteCount];
            inputStream.read(rawBytes);
            final String string = new String(rawBytes, "UTF-8");
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
              public void run() {
                if(string.contains("w")) {
                  textWeight.append(string);
                }
              }
            });
          }
        } 
        catch (IOException ex) {
          stopThread = true;
        }
      }
    }
  });
  thread1.start();
}
```

Comment: The same connection, several threads, no blocking, no locking? What could have possibly go wrong.

Comment: yeah when i calling first method and assign value to text view work correctly.but when i called the second method and assign value to next textview not working properly..some values print in ealier methods textview. @KIIV